# Get the name of the currently executing function in Angular 2 and TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

This question is for an Angular 2 application with TypeScript.

I need to log a custom message, the name of the class or component, and the name of the function from where I am logging.

Right now, I am hard-coding those values (again this is TypeScript):

```
class MyService {
  getUsers() {
    console.log('MyService.getUsers()', 'I am here');
  }
```

But, I don't want to hardcode the name of the class and function.

I managed to get the name of the class or component:

```
console.log(MyService.name);
```

But how can I get the name of the currently executing function?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate of a question somewhere, but I'll answer it anyway.

Comment: It's not possible to get `MyService.getUsers` string reliably and consistently inside called method. These names turn into junk in minified app. If the method is called with wrong context, you will end up with no `MyService` part . Don't be lazy and hard-code them.

Answer (score 0):

This answer requires Lodash for some basic functions. You should be able to replace that code with their JavaScript counterpart.

### LogService.ts

```
import {FactoryProvider, Injectable, InjectionToken, Optional} from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

const PREFIX_SEPARATOR = ':';

@Injectable()
export class LogService {
    /**
     * Global logger
     */
    public static log: LogService = new LogService();

    /**
     * Creates an injectable logger that can be used by a module.
     */
    public static provide(token: InjectionToken<LogService>): FactoryProvider {
        return {
            provide: token,
            useFactory: (log: LogService) => {
                let prefix = token.toString().replace(/^InjectionToken\s/, '').replace(/Logger$/, '').toUpperCase();
                return log.prefix(prefix);
            },
            deps: [LogService]
        };
    }

    /**
     * Gets the stack trace when browser adds stack property.
     */
    private static getStackTrace(): string[] | undefined {
        try {
            let ex = new Error() as Object;
            if (ex.hasOwnProperty('stack') && _.isString(ex['stack'])) {
                return ex['stack'].split('\n');
            }
        } catch (err) {
            // do nothing
        }
        return void 0;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the constructor name from the call stack, but only on Chrome browsers.
     */
    private static getConstructorName(depth: number): string | undefined {
        if (_.isUndefined(window['chrome'])) {
            return void 0;
        }
        let trace = LogService.getStackTrace();
        if (!trace || trace.length <= depth) {
            return void 0;
        }
        let str = trace[depth];
        if (!/\s+at\snew\s/.test(str)) {
            return void 0;
        }
        let match = /new ([$A-Z_][0-9A-Z_$]*)/i.exec(str);
        if (!match || match.length < 2) {
            return void 0;
        }
        return match[1].replace(/(Component|Directive|Service|Factory|Pipe|Resource|Module|Resolver|Provider)$/, '');
    }

    /**
     * Output prefix
     */
    private prefixName: string;

    /**
     * Flag if debugging is enabled.
     */
    private _debug: boolean = process.env.ENV && process.env.ENV === 'development';

    /**
     * Allows for optional prefix.
     */
    public constructor(@Optional() prefix?: string) {
        this.prefixName = prefix;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a logger with an automatic prefix.
     */
    public withPrefix(): LogService {
        if (!this._debug) {
            return this;
        }
        return this.prefix(LogService.getConstructorName(4));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new logger with the given prefix in all output messages.
     */
    public prefix(prefix?: string): LogService {
        return prefix
            ? new LogService((this.prefixName || '') + prefix + PREFIX_SEPARATOR)
            : this;
    }

    public get info(): Function {
        if (!console || !console.info) {
            return _.noop;
        }
        return this.prefixName
            ? console.info.bind(console, this.prefixName)
            : console.info.bind(console);
    }

    public get debug(): Function {
        if (!this._debug || !console || !console.log) {
            return _.noop;
        }
        return this.prefixName
            ? console.log.bind(console, this.prefixName)
            : console.log.bind(console);
    }

    public get warn(): Function {
        if (!console || !console.warn) {
            return _.noop;
        }
        return this.prefixName
            ? console.warn.bind(console, this.prefixName)
            : console.warn.bind(console);
    }

    public get error(): Function {
        if (!console || !console.error) {
            return _.noop;
        }
        return this.prefixName
            ? console.error.bind(console, this.prefixName)
            : console.error.bind(console);
    }
}
```

### LogService.module.ts

You have to export this service as a singleton in your `ngModule`, and then call `forRoot()` in your main module. In your other modules you import this module as normal.

```
@NgModule({
})
export class LogModule {
    public static forRoot() {
        return {
            ngModule: LogModule,
            providers: [
                LogService
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

### Creating loggers per module

You can create loggers that prefix each module name, by creating an injectable token for that module.

This example is for a UI module.

```
export const UI_LOGGER = new InjectionToken<LogService>('UILogger');

@NgModule({
    providers: [
        LogService.provide(UI_LOGGER)
    ]
})
export class UIModule {
}
```

You can not inject this new logger into your UI components.

```
@Component({})
export class MyComponent {
    private log: LogService; // logger with constructor name

    public constructor(@Inject(UI_LOGGER) log: LogService) {
        this.log = log.withPrefix();
    }
}
```

Calling `log.withPrefix()` creates a new logger with the constructor name, and also has the module name.

Comment: Please read the question again, he is looking for a way to get the method name not module name.

Comment: @SaiKiranMandhala `console.log(this.getUsers.name)` :)

Comment: +1 thanks that answer the question. Is there a generic way to get the current class and method names so that I copy-paste that in catch block !!?

Comment: No suitable injection token for parameter 'prefix' of class 'LogService'.
  Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.(-992003)
LogService.ts(77, 45): This type is not supported as injection token.